# Drupal 7: How to remove draft?

Tags: drupal-7

We use Workbench module in Drupal 7.

Users create drafts. Sometimes we need to delete a draft and preserve the pusblished version.
I know we can delete revision from "Moderate" tab. But that's not user intuitive.

Is there any way how to make it easier?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: Neil, unfortunately no :(